# session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters

Tags: php, macos, phpmyadmin, mamp

MAC OSX Yosemite 10.10.3を使用しています。

こちらでMAMPをインストールし、SQLサーバApache、並びにMAMPのトップ画面の起動に成功しました。

しかし、ここからツール→phpMyAdminを開くと以下のエラーが発生しSQL編集が行えません。 
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
エラーコード等で対応調べましたが、パーミッションの確認程度しか情報がありませんでした。 
(/Application/MAMP/tmp/phpのパーミッション。)

セッションのIDに不正な文字が入っているんでしょうか？ 
どちらから設定できますか？

Comment: 一旦ご利用頂いているブラウザのキャッシュをクリアしてみてはどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

`php.ini` で `session.use_strict_mode` を `Off` にするか

```
session.use_strict_mode = Off
```

ブラウザのクッキー(PHPSESSID) を削除してみて下さい。

http://blog.tokumaru.org/2013/08/php-5.5.2-strict-sessions.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185779/the-session-id-is-too-long-or-contains-illegal-characters-valid-characters-are

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございました。

Comment: @TatsuyoshiMizuno Congrats!